# Grouping object entries into object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

How can I create arrays to group members depending on their `tag`?

Tags can be anything, these are just examples.

Example Input

```js
[
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Steve' },
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Adam' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-John' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-James' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-Igor' }
]
```

Example Output

```js
{
  Red: ['Red-Steve', 'Red-Adam']
  Blue: ['Blue-John', 'Blue-James', 'Blue-Igor']
}
```

---

Edit: I just made a test case on `jsperf` to compare the efficiency of the different answers and also the answer from the suggested duplicate question
https://jsperf.com/group-objects-reduce-vs-for-loop

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62076217/13176517) by @Majed Badawi was the most efficient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: I edited my question with the jsperf link that shows the most efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `set` to group them by `tag` as follows:

```js
let list = [
            { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Steve' },
            { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Adam' },
            { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-John' },
            { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-James' },
            { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-Igor' }
];
let set = {};
for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
     let current = list[i];
     if(!set[current.tag])
          set[current.tag] = [current.member];
     else
          set[current.tag].push(current.member);
}
console.log(set);
```

Answer (score 1):

collect into object map using tag as key and appending to an array

```js
d=[
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Steve' },
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Adam' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-John' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-James' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-Igor' }
]
console.log(
d.reduce((acc,{tag,member})=>({...acc, [tag]: [...acc[tag]||[], member]}),{})
)
```

Comment: sure, it is iterating over the array of objects using reduce, using destructuring to extract `tag` and `member` property, acc is the "accumulated" value returned after every iteration, then it is merging the accumulated object map with a new property [tag] (which will be Red or Blue) and then concatenating member to the array

Comment: all of these answers are basically doing the same thing.  mine may incur a performance penalty on very large operations due to creating an object on every iteration.  it just happens to take a shorter "functional" approach

Comment: That's what I'm trying to decide here since I might end up working with a large number of objects, do you think a `for` loop would be more efficient than `reduce` here?

Comment: I'd go with whatever you're comfortable with.  I don't think you'll actually see a noticeable difference if your data structure is like the one you gave.  And, if you used `reduce` without using the `spread` syntax to merge objects (for example you could use Object.assign instead or direct assignment like the other answers), you could avoid the object initialization penalty.  If you want to be sure, I'd do a jsperf benchmark with something as close as possible to your dataset to check.

Comment: I just benchmarked with 100 objects and the `for` loop was obviously the winner. I used https://jsben.ch/ for the record.

Comment: Ah, that's good.  You should post it as a comment on your question, for future users to see.

Comment: Sorry, I should post what exactly?

Comment: The link to your jsperf benchmark.  You save the url to your bench as a comment on this question.  It'll probably be helpful to future search results for people who wanted to know the performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do what you ask. It uses the object[variableKey] syntax to get what you are looking for.

```
const members=[
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Steve' },
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Adam' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-John' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-James' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-Igor' }
]

//this will be the output object
const newObj={};

for(memberObj of members){
    const newKey = memberObj.tag;

    //if the key already existed, just add the new item to the existing array
    if(newObj[newKey]){newObj[newKey].push(memberObj.member);}
    //if the key didn't exist, create an array value for it with the new object
    else{newObj[newKey]=[memberObj.member];}
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be a good way of achieving it in modern syntax. But may be there are some aggregate functions too.

```js
var arr = [
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Steve' },
  { tag: 'Red', member: 'Red-Adam' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-John' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-James' },
  { tag: 'Blue', member: 'Blue-Igor' }
];

var newArr = [];
arr.forEach(o => {
  var existing = newArr[o.tag] && newArr[o.tag].length > 0 ? newArr[o.tag] : [];
  newArr[o.tag] = [...existing, ...[o.member]];
});

console.log('newArr', newArr);
```

In Chrome it is giving following output in the console

[image: Chrome Console Output]

We have a similar question here [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: If you see a dupe you should vote to close and reference that as a duplicate.

Comment: Hmm. Good suggestion

Comment: As I mentioned in the latest edit of my question, I added a link to a test case that tests the accepted answer of the question you linked as well as the 2 methods answered here. The answer of the question you linked was 20% slower than the accepted answer of this question.